# Erlang: push and pull from a shared queue

Tags: erlang

I need to maintain a shared queue where I can push data and a separate thread will periodically check and pull data from the queue if its not empty. I came up with the below solution where I can send data to the process and it adds up to a list. However, is there a cleaner / easier solution to do this ?

And im not sure how I may pull data from the below code.

```
-module(abc).
-export(queue/0).
queue() ->
    receive
        {push, Xmpp} ->
            io:format("Push"),
            queue(Xmpp);
        {pull} ->
            io:format("pull"),
            queue()
    end.

queue(E) ->
    receive
        {push, Xmpp} ->
            io:format("Push ~w",[E]),
            E1 = lists:append([E],[Xmpp]),
            queue(E1);
        {reset} ->
            queue([])
    end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code probably won't do exactly what you want as written.  When you call `queue/1` from the `receive` block ( `queue(Xmpp);` in line 7), `queue/1` will fire and then wait for a message.  Because this is not spawned in a separate process, `queue/0` will block (since `queue/1` is now waiting for a message that is never sent).

Also, `queue/0` won't ever send anything back to the process sending it messages. It has no way of returning data to the sender.

The following will work (you will need to send messages to the pid returned by `queue/0`).

```
-module(abc).
-export([queue/0,queue/1]).

queue() ->
    %% initialize an empty queue,
    %% return the Pid to the caller
    spawn(abc,queue,[[]]).




queue(E) when is_list(E) ->
    receive
        %% append the message value to the existing list
        {push, Xmpp} ->
            io:format("Pushing ~w to ~w~n",[Xmpp,E]),
            E1 = lists:append(E,[Xmpp]),
            queue(E1);

        %% reset the queue
        {reset} ->
            queue([]);

        %% return the value to the caller
        %% "Pid" must be a Pid
        {pull, Pid} when is_pid(Pid) ->
            io:format("pull~n"),
            Pid ! E,
            queue(E)
    end.
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a problem with a straightforward solution in Erlang. Most of the time every erlang module you will be programming will be like a server, which will expect messages and will answer, you can have 0, 1 or mulitple servers running the same erlang module code. At the same time, you will be programming in the same module a client, which is an easy way to send messages to the server without having to know all the message format the server expect, instead you use functions, so instead of doing stuff like

```
Server ! {put, Value},
receive 
    {Server, {ok, Value}} ->
        everything_ok;
    {Server, {error, Reason}} ->
        handle_error
end,
```

you end doing something like

```
my_module:put(Server, Value).
```

So you can create a server process in erlang with the code:

```
-module(abc).
-export([start/0, put/2, pop/1, reset/1, is_empty/1, loop/1]).

%% Client

start() ->
    spawn(?MODULE, loop, [[]]).

put(Pid, Item) ->
    Pid ! {self(), {put, Item}},
    receive
        {Pid, {ok, Item}} ->
            Item;
        {Pid, {error, Reason}} ->
            {error, Reason}
    after 500 ->
            timeout
    end.

pop(Pid) ->
    Pid ! {self(), {pop}},
    receive
        {Pid, {ok, Item}} ->
            Item;
        {Pid, {error, Reason}} ->
            {error, Reason}
    after 500 ->
            timeout
    end.

reset(Pid) ->
    Pid ! {self(), {reset}},
    receive
        {Pid, {ok}} ->
            ok;
        _ ->
            error
    after 500 ->
            timeout
    end.

is_empty(Pid) ->
    Pid ! {self(), {is_empty}},
    receive
        {Pid, {true}} ->
            true;
        {Pid, {false}} ->
            false;
        _ ->
            error
    after 500 ->
            timeout
    end.

%% Server

loop(Queue) ->
    receive
        {From, {put, Item}} when is_pid(From) ->      
            From ! {self(), {ok, Item}},
            loop(Queue ++ [Item]);
        {From, {pop}} when is_pid(From) ->
            case Queue of
                [] -> 
                    From ! {self(), {error, empty}},
                    loop(Queue);
                [H|T] ->
                    From ! {self(), {ok, H}},
                    loop(T)
            end;
        {From, {reset}} when is_pid(From) ->
            From ! {self(), {ok}},
            loop([]);
        {From, {is_empty}} when is_pid(From) ->
            case Queue of
                [] ->
                    From ! {self(), {true}},
                    loop(Queue);
                _ ->
                    From ! {self(), {false}},
                    loop(Queue)
            end;
        _ ->
            loop(Queue)
    end.
```

and the code you end writting to use is simple as well:

```
(emacs@rorra)1> c("/Users/rorra/abc", [{outdir, "/Users/rorra/"}]).     
{ok,abc}      

(emacs@rorra)2> Q = abc:start().       
<0.44.0>

(emacs@rorra)3> abc:is_empty(Q).       
true

(emacs@rorra)4> abc:pop(Q).       
{error,empty}

(emacs@rorra)5> abc:put(Q, 23).       
23

(emacs@rorra)6> abc:is_empty(Q).       
false

(emacs@rorra)7> abc:pop(Q).       
23

(emacs@rorra)8> abc:pop(Q).       
{error,empty}

(emacs@rorra)9> abc:put(Q, 23).       
23

(emacs@rorra)10> abc:put(Q, 50).       
50

(emacs@rorra)11> abc:reset(Q).       
ok

(emacs@rorra)12> abc:is_empty(Q).       
true
```

At the end to avoid all that repeated code you end using OTP and writting a gen_server for it.

I'm assuming you are building a queue on your own for learning, otherwise Erlang already has a good implementation for a Queue:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/queue.html

And the source code:

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/queue.erl

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed explanation. Ill check the erlang queue.